# Submitting form using jQuery ajax function Problem?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form containing two fields
When i submit the form using a jQuery ajax function the server only receive the first field data but not the second field data ?

> First Field: Dropdownlist (single value selection.)
>
> Second Field: Dropdownlist (Multi value selection.)

Here is my Code:

**Form:**

```
<form id="formId">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "id", "name"), "Select Customer", new { @class = "form-control", id = "customer_Id" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Book</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Books, new MultiSelectList(Model.Books, "id", "name"), "Select Books", new { multiple = "true", @class = "form-control", id = "Book_Ids" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var viewModel = {
                Customers: "",
                Books: []
            };
            
            // Loading data to viewModel.
            $("#btn_Test").on("click", function () {
                var selectedCustomerId = $("#customer_Id").val();
                var selectedBooksIds = $("#Books_Ids").val();
                viewModel.Customers = selectedCustomerId;
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedBooksIds .length; i++) {
                    viewModel.Books.push(parseInt(selectedBooksIds[i]));//Added parseInt to parse value to int
                }
            });

            // Submit Form.
            $("#formId").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/RecordCustomerAndBooksIds/Create",
                    method: "post",
                    data: viewModel,
                    success: function () { alert("Done."); },
                    fail: function () { alert("Failed."); }
                });
            })

        });
    </script>
}
```

**ViewModel:** (When User click submitting the form the target viewModel will recieve the appropriate Id's.)

```
public class CustomerIdAndBooksIdsViewModel
{
   public int Customers { get; set; }
   public List<int> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method:**

When submitting form: the CustomerIdAndBooksIdsViewModel Object receiving only Customers(customer Id) and the Books(books Ids) is null ?

```
public ActionResult Create(CustomerIdAndBooksIdsViewModel ids) //
{
   //...
}
```

> **How to Solve it ?I Shall be very thanksful.**

Comment: Is this a typo in the question? `viewModel.Books*s*.push(selectedBooksIds[i]);`

Comment: @Peter Sorry for it..it was happen during editing question...

Comment: have you tried using an array of int in the viewmodel instead of a list? (int[] Books {get; set;})  the binding on a mvc can be very picky when it comes to what it will bind.

Comment: yes....i tried that as well....same as the case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is in `viewModel.Books`, you are pushing as string but on controller's Action it is expecting an list of int.

Try parsing the values to INT before posting the values, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedBooksIds.length; i++) 
{
   //Added parseInt to parse value to int
   viewModel.Books.push(parseInt(selectedBooksIds[i]));
}
```

Comment: ViewModel still receives a null value for Books.

Answer (score 0):

try using `select2`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    //The url we will send our get request to
    var booksUrl = '@Url.Action("GetBooks", "Home")';
    $('#books').select2(
    {
        placeholder: 'Select Books',
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            //The url of the json service
            url: booksUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
            }
    }
  });
 </script>



<form id="formId">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "id", "name"), "Select Customer", new { @class = "form-control", id = "customer_Id" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Book</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Books, new { id = "Book_Ids" }) 
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: In my case ... in the second dropdownlist i am retreiving All Book list from a viewModel....in your case how to do that ?

Comment: The official select2 site is here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
You should request the list from a method that will give you the list of objects.  Request from inside select2 using ajax option.  In your back end create the method called.  I have updated the answer for you